# Drush installed and running; No Drupal site found even with uri specified

Tags: drush, 7

After much trial and tribulation, I thought I had drush all ready to roar. Much excitement. But then, no joy...

Drush is working. The sites operate fine via MAMP. Regardless, a "drush cc all" command returns:

```
No Drupal site found, only 'drush' cache was cleared.                                          [warning]
'all' cache was cleared.                                                                       [success]
```

This question has stumped drupalcon attendees and very experienced developers. Any ideas?

I am on Mac OS 10.9.3
using MAMP (free) Version 3.0.5

Here is my drush status:

```
 Drupal version         :  7.29-dev                               
 Site URI               :  http://default                         
 Database driver        :  mysql                                  
 Database hostname      :  localhost                              
 Database username      :  db_user                           
 Database name          :  db_name                      
 PHP executable         :  /usr/bin/php                           
 PHP configuration      :                                         
 PHP OS                 :  Darwin                                 
 Drush version          :  7.0-dev                                
 Drush temp directory   :  /tmp                                   
 Drush configuration    :                                         
 Drush alias files      :                                         
 Drupal root            :  /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/mysite.dev 
 Site path              :  sites/default
```

Have tried executing drush from `/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/mysite.dev`; from `/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/mysite.dev/sites/default`; and using `drush cc all --uri=http://localhost/mysite.dev`

Tried running drush from sites/default. Same result.

Comment: is your database connection located in the sites/default folder?  If so try just running drush cc from that folder.  I dont think --uri is a valid argument for drush cc

Comment: Tried running drush from sites/default. Same result.

Comment: Did you find a resolution for this. I've the same issue and similar setup.

Comment: I did not. I am still drush-less.

Comment: Have you looked at this one? It looks similar off the top: http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/98802/drush-does-not-work-on-my-mac

Answer (score 9):

Please double check that all below points are addressed.

1. You're running `drush` in Drupal root folder or folder containing `settings.php` file.
2. The `mysql` command exists (and it's in your `PATH`).

   Please note that the database command depends on your database `driver` set in your settings file (e.g. `sqlcmd` for SQL Server; for details check different classes in Drush's [`/src/Sql`](https://github.com/drush-ops/drush/tree/master/src/Sql)).

   If the command is missing when running in any folder, make sure path to its binary file is added into your `PATH` system variable.
3. Your PHP has [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) extension enabled (check by: **`php -m | grep pdo`** or `drush sqlc`).
4. Your PHP has [database extension](http://php.net/manual/en/refs.database.vendors.php) enabled (e.g. [`mysqli`](http://php.net/mysql)) (check by: **`php -m | grep mysql`**).

To investigate what's exactly wrong, run `drush` with `-v` (verbose) and `-d` (debug) flags, e.g.

```
drush -vd status
drush -vd ev "echo 123"
drush -vd cc all
```

and check for any errors.

---

> mysql extension for PHP PDO is not installed. Check your php.ini to see how you can enable it.

Install [database extension](http://php.net/manual/en/refs.database.vendors.php) (e.g. [`mysqli`](http://php.net/mysql)) (as per above 4th point).

For MAMP, see: [Drush does not work on my Mac](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/q/98802/1908)

---

#### MAMP

Since you're using MAMP, make also sure you running the right version of `php` binary (check by `which php`) and it should point to `/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.X.X/bin/php`. If not, please add the path into your `PATH` in your *rc* files (e.g. `~/.bashrc`):

```
# For MAMP (OSX)
PHP_VER="5.6.10" # Or: 5.4.19/5.5.3 (check by: $ ls /Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php*)
export PATH="$PATH:/Applications/MAMP/Library/bin:/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php$PHP_VER/bin:/Developer/usr/bin"
```

---

#### XAMPP

For XAMPP for Windows, similar thing, add your `C:\xampp\mysql\bin` into your environment variable `PATH`.

#### Debugging

If your `drush` command fails for some reason, here are the suggested steps to debug drush (shell commands).

1. Install and enable [PHP `xdebug` extension](https://xdebug.org/). Verify by `php71 -i | grep xdebug`.
2. Verify *Drupal root*, *Settings File* and *Database* are present in `drush status`.
3. Generate trace file:

   ```
   drush ev "xdebug_start_trace(); drush_drupal_cache_clear_all(); echo xdebug_get_tracefile_name(); xdebug_stop_trace();"
   ```

   or:

   ```
   drush ev "xdebug_start_trace(); print_r(_core_site_status_table()); echo xdebug_get_tracefile_name(); xdebug_stop_trace();"
   ```

   <sup>If xdebug is enabled for different PHP version, specify with `DRUSH_PHP=/path/to/php`.</sup>

   If successful, trace output file should be printed at the end, so take a note of it.
4. Now open and check the trace file.
5. To test or compare drush output with clean Drupal, you can install new Drupal in empty folder by:

   ```
   drush -y qd --no-server --core=drupal-8
   cd quick-drupal-*/drupal*
   drush status
   ```

Comment: +1 really nice answer, going beyond the obvious check settings.php and db. Particularly for me `drush sqlc` helped me as it showed that the database could not be connected to with the user, which led me to check the user and password and revealed that I had set them up wrong. Thank you!

Comment: I had a similar issue to @therobyouknow - I had a `~/.my.cnf` file which specified user for mysql connections but not a password. I think this was resulting in drush using the user from that file with the password from the site, which was invalid. Adding a password into my `~/.my.cnf` file, or removing that file entirely fixed the problem

Answer (score 5):

Had the same problem with the new Drush 8 on my Mac running MAMP

You need add this to your .bash_profile
export PATH=/Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/:$PATH.

once added make sure to open a new terminal window as it won't work on your current window as bash needs to start up again.

Comment: This one throwaway line is what fixed it for me. I was pulling my hair out on this one. OPEN A NEW TERMINAL WINDOW WHEN YOU MAKE UPDATES/CHANGES to bash! Otherwise your new settings wont take affect.

Answer (score 1):

To clear All Cache using Drush, you have to go the directory of the site on the terminal where your site directory located like in www or htdocs directory and then your project folder after that run the command :

```
drush cc all
```

Answer (score 1):

As @kenorb said, use `drush -vd cc all`, it will give you a good idea about what is happening in detail. In my case, it was due to the error `"mysql command not found"`. I solved it by setting up the path for mysql in my environment variables. 
I feel you need to check your path as well, for Drush and MySQL both and see if it works.

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

Running MAMP Pro I got this to work by adding this line into my `~/.bash_profile` file:

```
export PATH=$PATH:/Applications/MAMP/Library/bin
```

Answer (score 0):

Checkout the Drush package configure.md, it has a bunch of helpful hints for platforms, the MAMP section is thus:

> ### Additional Configurations for Mamp:
>
> Users of MAMP will need to manually specify in their PATH which version of php
>   and MySQL to use in the command line interface. This is independent of the php
>   version selected in the MAMP application settings.  Under OS X, edit (or create
>   if it does not already exist) a file called .bash_profile in your home folder.
>
> To use php 5.3.x, add this line to .bash_profile:
>
> ```
> export PATH="/Applications/MAMP/Library/bin:/Applications/MAMP/bin/php5.3/bin:$PATH"
> ```
>
> If you want to use php 5.4.x, add this line instead:
>
> ```
> export PATH="/Applications/MAMP/Library/bin:/Applications/MAMP/bin/php5.4/bin:$PATH"
> ```
>
> If you use MAMP 3 (php 5.5.14 by default) and want to use php 5.5.x , add this line instead:
>
> ```
> export PATH="/Applications/MAMP/Library/bin:/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.5.14/bin:$PATH"
> ```
>
> If you have MAMP v.1.84 or lower, this configuration will work for both versions
>   of PHP:
>
> ```
> export PATH="/Applications/MAMP/Library/bin:/Applications/MAMP/bin/php5/bin:$PATH"
> ```
>
> If you have done this and are still getting a "no such file or directory" error
>   from PDO::__construct, try this:
>
> `bash
>     sudo mkdir /var/mysql
>     sudo ln -s /Applications/MAMP/tmp/mysql/mysql.sock /var/mysql/mysql.sock`
>
> Additionally, you may need to adjust your php.ini settings before you can use
>   drush successfully. See CONFIGURING PHP.INI below for more details on how to
>   proceed.